# how to set a variable to 0 after a value has been stored in variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Thanks so much!

I am working on an application that has a tap counter to set a quantity in a label then the label value is multiplied by the quantity set by the tap counter,

the label will reset to 0 , but the tap counter does not, so when user taps on counter it starts from last count

```
   @implementation ViewController

   //These are the tap counter buttons .m//

   - (IBAction)oneClicker:(UIButton *)sender
   {
       counter++;
       [_fourLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter]];
   }

    - (IBAction)oneAClicker:(UIButton *)sender
   {   
       counter--;
       [_fourLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter]];


    // these are the calculate & reset buttons in .m //






    - (IBAction)calculateButton:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        double total = ([self.fourLabel.text integerValue] * 4)+ ([self.sixLabel.text integerValue] * 6)+ ([self.ninetyFiveLabel.text integerValue] * 0.95)+ ([self.twoLabel.text integerValue] * 2)+ ([self.twoaLabel.text integerValue] * 2)+ ([self.threeLabel.text integerValue] * 3)+ ([self.oneFiftyLabel.text integerValue] * 1.5);

        self.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f",total];
    }

    - (IBAction)resetButton:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        self.fourLabel.text = @"0";
        self.sixLabel.text = @"0";
        self.ninetyFiveLabel.text = @"0";
        self.twoaLabel.text = @"0";
        self.twoLabel.text = @"0";
        self.threeLabel.text = @"0";
        self.oneFiftyLabel.text = @"0";
        self.totalLabel.text = @"$0";
        // self.fourLabel.text = @"";
    }

        // this is .h i will just show a few //
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
NSInteger counter;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fourLabel;

- (IBAction)calculateButton:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)resetButton:(UIButton *)sender;
```

Comment: I think your code is incomplete and cut halfway. Can you please edit the post?

Comment: Yup. your code included stuff that has no bearing on the question (I trimmed it) and the code you did post has little relation to the text you wrote. There's no multiplication, no showing where the counter or label are defined...

Comment: how did you reset label to 0? show the code

Comment: Thanks all for input I updated the question

Comment: You have a method `resetButton` in which you reset your labels to `@"0"`. Is there a reason why you do not also reset your `counter` to `0` at this time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
counter = 0;
```

This assumes that counter is an integer.   If its something else, just adjust accordingly.

Comment: sorry I am naive where would you put counter = 0;

Comment: Somebody edited your question, or I misread it, anyway, what is it exactly that you want to do?  If you want to reset the counter along with the label use the following command  counter = 0, in another function, multiple and move the counter value to your label.text .... label.text = [NSString stringwithfomat:@"%d", counter];   Your question is very elementary, I would suggest going through the sample apps, these kind of routines are all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for your input , I am elementary and will look at more sample apps. I do want to reset counter , but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: .... place the counter = 0 in the - (IBAction)resetButton:(UIButton *)sender. I notice that your compute routine  converts the text to integer before computing ... and then back to text to display the labels. I find that expensive (it slows down your app), I would suggest setting up separate integer variables for your values so your compute routine deals with the integer values only, then setup a common routine just to move the variables to the labels.

Comment: Ok I feel kinda stupid the counter = 0 was pretty dam easy.I will try to wrap my head around just using integers

Comment: Good luck, no problem, each one of us started from 0. its not easy to move from 1 language syntax to another. Just wonder why some nasty people keep marking down these questions and answers.I hope you don't mind accepting this answer so I can get my 2 point back.

Comment: Thanks for your help Paulo! I am still learning how stack overflow works.